# What is the correct way to extend the functionality of a CocoaPod library?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I wrote a class which extends PureLayout, a popular CocoaPod library. I am currently moving my extension classes into a Cocoa Touch Framework in order to improve reusability and organize my project. When I move the PureLayout extension into the new framework target (JFLibs), I get an error `No such module 'PureLayout'`.

I can change my podfile to include PureLayout for the new target, but is that the right way to handle this? Should I be organizing my files differently? What's the right way to handle a CocoaPod dependency in your own custom libraries?